# How to iterate through the below Nestested HashMap in Java

Tags: java, collections

I want to iterate through the below `HashMap`. I want to retrieve both key and values from this.

```
HashMap<String,List<HashMap<String, List<String >>>> maps = new HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, List<String>>>>();
```

Comment: Yuck. But okay, what's the problem?

Comment: Depends on what you need to iterate. The main key set? The values? The values' key sets? The values' values?

Comment: Thanks a lot .. This worked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
HashMap<String,List<HashMap<String, List<String >>>> maps = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<HashMap<String, List<String>>>> entry : maps.entrySet()) {
    for (HashMap<String, List<String>> map : entry.getValue()) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> subEntry : map.entrySet()) {
            for (String value : subEntry.getValue()) {
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: @Tom good one thank you :-)

Comment: @NicolasFilotto nice solution. Took me a while to even read that map right :D

Comment: @AniMenon yes it is a tricky one :-)